# Detect Huawei app is uninstalled from phone

Tags: push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I'm having difficulty figuring out if the user has deleted my app from their Huawei phone when sending a Push.

I'm looking at the [push docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/quickapp-access-push-kit), I do not see any error code for this case. Also, looking at the [sample app](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-push-serverdemo-go/blob/master/src/push/constant/constants.go#L68) that Huawei has given, I can't see it there either.

Does anyone know exactly what I need to look for when sending a push to Huawei to detect if an app is deleted from the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One gets posted a [receipt state](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/msg-receipt-guide-0000001050040176) with value `2`, when the app isn't installed anymore.

> If the app does not exist after the message is successfully sent to the device, the app has been uninstalled.

My [ReceiptStatus.php](https://github.com/syslogic/php-hms/blob/master/src/PushKit/ReceiptStatus.php#L68) would feature these values, but not yet implemented.